# Trying to get number of rows containing '/2020' in a column

Tags: csv, awk

I have a sizeable dataset of about 7 million lines and I am trying to find the number of rows in column $2 that contain "/2020" in the date ($2 is all dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy). However, all of the `awk` commands I'm trying are either giving me 0 or aren't printing anything at all, and I'm not sure why.

```
awk -F',' '$2 == "/2020" { count++ } END { print count }' file.csv
```

prints nothing

```
awk -v variable="2020" '$2 ~ variable' file.csv | wc -l
```

prints 0

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0;} { if ($2 =="2020") count += 1} END {print count}' file.csv
```

prints 0

I'd appreciate some help. thanks!

Comment: Your second and third versions are missing `-F','`. The second version would work if you fixed this.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to use is:

```sh
awk -F, '$2 ~ /\/2020/{cnt++} END {print cnt}' file.csv
```

`==` would mean that second field will be exactly like the pattern, while `~` means that it is matching the pattern, just a part of the field can be like the pattern.

See also the related part of the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Usage)

Also, your second attempt would have worked if you have added the field separator, note that here you match only the year without the slash.

```sh
awk -F, -v variable="2020" '$2 ~ variable' file.csv | wc -l
```

Note: Assuming that there are no separators (commas) nested into quotes fields in your file, at least for the first two fields. If there are, a more complex pattern should be used as the field separator.

Answer (score 2):

Combination of the best parts of your trials is:

```
$ awk -F, -v variable=2020 '$2~variable{c++}END{print c}' file
2
```

Since *$2 is all dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy* no need to put the `/` in the query (avoid an escaping), 2020 is enough - when using earthbound calendars...
But without a proper sample this is still all guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following if you want to use variable.

```
awk -v variable="2020" 'BEGIN{FS=","} $2 ~ ("/"variable){cnt++} END{print cnt}' file.csv
```